# latexdiff-vc file names

Tags: latex

I am using git with a latex project but it seems that I am not using latexdiff in an efficient way.

In order to run latexdiff to compare the current version with the previous revision, I learned to use:

```
latexdiff-vc -r HEAD~1 main.tex
```

Further info here: [www.mankier.com/1/latexdiff-vc](https://www.mankier.com/1/latexdiff-vc)

The `HEAD~1` above picks the previous git revision, which is something that I find useful.

However, the generated diff file has the following name `main-diffHEAD~1.tex`, which I find a terrible name: both for clarity and since my tex editor has issues with the `~`.

Due to the issue, my questions are:

1. Am I properly using `-r HEAD~1`, or is there another more natural way to do the same comparison?
2. Is there a simple way to control the file name output instead of renaming it? Say, `main-diff1.tex` would be better.

Comment: The `-r` is fine; the generated file name isn't up to Git though, it's just up to latexdiff. Neither tag is really right - you should ask this of the author of latexdiff.

Comment: @torek, yes, the generated name is up to latexdiff, but the syntax `HEAD~1`, I understand it comes from git. I am no git expert. I was in doubt if there was another way for referring to the previous revision. When I am not using git, I use `latexdiff file1.tex file2.tex > diff.tex` to generate the `diff.tex` file. But this `latexdiff-vc`, which is useful within git, seems not flexible enough for choosing the output filename easily. I end up needing to use `mv` to change the file name, so I thought that perhaps I am doing something wrong...

Comment: The alternative to `HEAD~1` is `HEAD^` or `HEAD~` or `HEAD^1`: all equally awkward.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the hash in is the filename you can run this:

```bash
$ latexdiff-vc --git -r `git rev-parse --short HEAD~1` main.tex
```

where `HEAD~1` can be replaced with any of the alternatives mentioned by [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in the question comments.

I personally use this quite often so have the sub-command as an alias in my `~/.gitconfig`, like so:

```bash
[alias]
  shash = "!git rev-parse --short HEAD"
```

and then actually run the same command from above as:

```bash
$ latexdiff-vc --git -r `git shash HEAD~1` main.tex
```